# Android jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu's animation is not smooth when changes fragment

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I use jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu as my slidingmenu for my app and the slidingmenu will change different fragment for a activity.When the fragment contains only one or two items it seems good.But if I tried to make the fragment contains more thing ,the slidingmenu will be a short stop when I change the fragment.The animation is not smooth

Is there anyway to slove the problem?Thanks.

Comment: To be sure if I understand your problem is animation is not smooth when the fragment has many objects?

Comment: @subspider Yes,that is what the problem

Comment: How are you testing ? device or emulator ? if is devices please take care that it might behave differently in different devices.

Comment: @subspider Thank you.I test it in devices like nexus4 or samsung S3 and I think the ability of devices is enough.And I find some other apps could change smooth although I don't know if they use this lib.

Comment: nice to see that was a testing problem I've being using this on my apps. I recommend it. :)

Comment: @subspider So do you use some method to make it smooth?To me it's not a testing problem but a product problem :)

Comment: I do not use fragment one since I have old apps with old tabbar implementation but for me it works smooth. So I can't tell you why. Maybe you can get more info on the giithug project.

Comment: did u fix this issue ??

Answer (score 2):

I experience same animation lag when I'm showing heavy fragment.
I tried to close menu with animation and show fragment with animation at same time. The animation was laggy, even with native drawer.

So the way to go is:

1. set menuOnClose listener
2. on menu item click remember the choice
3. close menu
4. in onCloseListener show fragment.

that works great for me.

Comment: Thank you.I tried this.It's fine,but it will also take some time to refresh the view after the menu closed.Is there anyway to optimize it?

Comment: I'd like to remove that delay also, but still didn't found a way.
Another approach I tried yesterday: change fragment, then close menu. This way speed up user experience slightly (to be honesty - time of closing and changing fragment is the same, but delay between changing fragment is less noticeable).

To do this:
1. Override onCreateAnimation of Fragment and add listener to it and add animation listener there.
2. In that onAnimationEnd() listener close menu.

Comment: Can u please provide the sample code of what u just said ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a somewhat clunky solution for this but it works okay. 
I use a base class for my fragments which is called `BaseFragment`. In this class I override the `onResume` method and close the menu if it is showing:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(sm.isMenuShowing()){
        sm.showContent();
    }
}
```

`sm` is a reference for a `SlidingMenu` from the `SlidingFragmentActivity`.

This will make the animation smoother but it will create a small delay between the click on a menu button and the start of the close animation. In my case this worked better then when the animation stops mid-animation.